# How to programatically merge & render 3d models?

Tags: model, 3d

I want to write an application that let users customize some 3d objects, making new objects by combining existing ones. For example, if a user wants to change just the roof of a house, he should select a new one (other existing roof object) and the whole model (the whole house) would be updated. I haven´t found any way to do this merge programatically, so the alternative is 3d modeling each combination of objects, which is impractical even for a low number of customizable options.

Do you know any way to achieve this dynamical merging?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you store every customizable part of the house as a model? In your example, there would be a model of a house without a roof, models of all possible roofs, and then when you need a complete house drawn, you drawn a house without a roof + a roof chosen by user.

Comment: Of course, that's what I'm trying to achieve but... how can I create programatically a new 3d model from two different 3d models?

Comment: Why do you need it to be exactly a "model", whatever might you mean by that? Why don't you, say, just write a class called "CComposition", which would accept a list of models (of a house itself, and of it's parts) and draw them one by one?
Anyway, if you really need merging models (i.e. for saving), and not just rendering a merged model, at least specify the format in which your models are stored. Or else how would anybody know...

Comment: Ok, I apologize, maybe I haven't explained myself. My goal is to customize an object (that's what I mean when I say "model") composed of some other objects (again, some other models). The "models" are 3D Model files (for example, 3DStudioMax or "obj" files). So, the question is... how can I merge dynamically these models into a single one? how can I specify, in the models or in the merging process, the junction points? do you know any api (I'm working in Java) offering this functionality?
Thank you very much!